# Replay a non-looping gif image

Tags: java, swing, animation

I've got a non-looping gif that I use as ImageIcon for two JLabels, but not at the same time.

My problem is that when I set the second JLabel's icon to be the gif, the animation has already been played, so it only show the last frame of it.

Do you know a way to get the animation when the gif is set to the second JLabel?

Comment: Are you talking about a Swing application or web?

Comment: Tagged Java, using JLabel (swing component) .. Should be clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the newly created icon try using:

```
icon.getImage().flush();
```

Comment: lol had the same answer ready for some time too. but only hid the save edit button just now after doing some more tests. well whatever

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

discarded old answer. After some more searching around I found the way to do it.

```
ImageIcon icon = ..[the animated gif without looping]..
....
label1.setIcon(icon); //animation plays once
....
// now time to remove icon from label1 and add it to label2
label1.setIcon(null);
icon.getImage().flush(); //reset resource used by the image
label2.setIcon(icon);
....
```

[Java Api: Image#flush()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush())

btw. if you leave the line `label1.setIcon(null);` out it will still repeat the animation of the icon only for label2. label1 stays at the last frame.

Comment: First : Eclipse says : loadImage() is not visible for imageIcon.
Second : doesn't work (just show the last frame).