# Updating JLabel Icon with GIF eventually stops animations

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've been running into this issue where when I update the icon of a JLabel more than around~ 5 times the animation stops and it just shows the last frame of the gif. The gifs are meant to loop only once, not sure if this is relevant.
I'm using an ImageIcon and running

```
jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("path/blah.gif");
```

Any ideas why? 
Thanks

Comment: `ImageIcon` generally maintains a cached reference to the images that it has previously loaded, so it can load them faster in the future if required.  You might be able to use the `Image#flush` method to flush the cache and force the system to reload the image from scratch

Comment: As suggested in [Replay a non-looping gif image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718390/replay-a-non-looping-gif-image)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you! That worked.